# System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot workaround for UNC paths

Tags: .net

GetPathRoot doesn't seem to support UNC paths.  The result from the code below is simply trimming off file.txt

```
string root = Path.GetPathRoot("\\servername.pvt\sub dir\file.txt");
```

What is a good workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return value is correct.  The root is the **share**, and not the server!  For example:

```
Path.GetPathRoot(@"\\servername.pvt\sharename\directory\file.txt");
```

This returns `@"\\servername.pvt\sharename"`.  The server name plus the share name constitutes the path root.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot.aspx) examples show, for a UNC path, it is the server *and share name* that is considered the root directory.

If you want just the server name, it would be safe to assume that only one "path element" exists after the server which you could strip off yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get server UNC address think good solution is not use `Path.GetPathRoot`, only erase all after third `\` i think this will work in all cases.