# Check Drive Exists(string path)

Tags: c#, wpf

How to check the drive is exists in the system from the given string in WPF. I have tried the following

**Ex:** `FileLocation.Text = "K:\TestDrive\XXX";`

```
if (!Directory.Exists(FileLocation.Text))
{
         MessageBox.Show("Invalid Directory", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
         return;
}
```

It is checking full path but `it should check "K:\" from the text`. Could you please guide me

**EDIT 1:** "**K:\TestDrive\XXX**" is not static

**EDIT 2:** I tried the below, in my system i'm having `3 drives C, D and E` but it showing **false**.

```
Environment.SystemDirectory.Contains("D").ToString(); = "False"
```

Comment: Please make sure your samples have reasonable C# code. I.e. `"K:\Test..."` is somewhat suspicious string constant: should be `@"K:\Test..."` or `"K:\\Test..."`, checking for `true`/`false` does not require call for `ToString` and definitely not case sensitive comparison with strange `; =` operator.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Thanks for your comment, but i just given  for example

Comment: How about `Directory.Exists(Path.GetPathRoot(pathGoesHere))`?

Comment: Great working fine but if path has only \\\\, it fails and it should show alert if the path has '/'

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
string drive = Path.GetPathRoot(FileLocation.Text);   // e.g. K:\

if (!Directory.Exists(drive))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Drive " + drive + " not found or inaccessible", 
                     "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
     return;
}
```

Of course, additional sanity checks (does the path root have at least three characters, is the second one a colon) should be added, but this will be left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: [Path.GetPathRoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot.aspx) is better than substring...

Comment: Great working fine but if path has only \\\\, it fails and it should show alert if the path has '/'

Comment: @Ponmalar: `\\\\ ` is not a drive, so it *should* fail. Note that [GetPathRoot does work for UNC paths](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4230112/87698)!

Comment: Perfect. I was looking for a solution to check if a drive is un-formatted (inaccessible, like an encrypted TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt partition appears to windows). This does the job.

Comment: That is not 100% correct: if you insert a USB drive get its DriveInfo, eject it , insert another USB Drive your Method will return true for the DriveIndo of the first, because Windows will mount both under the same letter, it would be sager to check the Drive Name too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not work for drives that exist but have no media in them (e.g. CD-ROM drives with no CD in them). I.e. the method  shows the drive as inaccessible, but doesn't let one determine whether the drive letter is available or occupied (drive "exists").

Answer (score 8):

you can do follow

```
bool isDriveExists(string driveLetterWithColonAndSlash)
{
    return DriveInfo.GetDrives().Any(x => x.Name == driveLetterWithColonAndSlash);
}
```

Comment: What's the matter? You can not replace "@K:\" by another drive letter?

Answer (score 2):

This is Because Environment.SystemDirectory.XXXXX is all about where the system/windows is installed ...... not for whole HD.

for this you can use.....

```
    foreach (var item in System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
    }
```

it will show all drives including USBs that are attached.....

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Environment.GetLogicalDrives()` to obtain an `string[]` of logical drives in your system.

```
var drive = Path.GetPathRoot(FileLocation.Text);
if (Environment.GetLogicalDrives().Contains(drive, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
         MessageBox.Show("Invalid Directory", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
         return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this....

```
MessageBox.Show(Environment.SystemDirectory.Contains("D").ToString());
```

Comment: This is obviously wrong - drive comparison should be case insensitive (hence must use `IndexOf` with comparison type instead of `Contains`) and better check for "drive letter" + ":" to avoid cases where letter happened to be part of the path.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this depends on what exactly you are hoping to accomplish. If you are trying to iterate through the drives and test to make sure each drive exists, then `Environment.GetLogicalDrives()` or `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` is appropriate as it allows you to iterate through the drives.

However, if all you care about is testing to see if ONE drive exists for a particular path, getting the entire list of drives to check if it is contained is a bit backwards. You would want to use `Directory.Exists()` as it just checks if that single path exists.

```
bool DriveExists(string fileLocation) {
    string drive = Path.GetPathRoot(fileLocation); // To ensure we are just testing the root directory.

    return Directory.Exists(drive); // Does the path exist?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get if any drives' letter is E. You can change it to any other letter.

```
DriveInfo.GetDrives().Any(d => d.Name.ToUpper()[0] == 'E');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check drives in C# like this

```
   foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
   {
       //Code goes here
   }
```